# strtok based on a char * (string) instead of a single char

Tags: c, string, strtok

I'm trying to find a pattern within a string and remove it if it exists. I've been playing with `strtok(aString, "$%");`

This will break up the `aString` when it finds `$` or `%`.  How do I make it break it up when it ONLY finds `"$%"` within the string?

Comment: No way, write your own code. Use `strstr` to locate the occurrence of the string, then copy it over a new buffer (or the same buffer).

Comment: When you say "remove it if it exists" do you mean trim out the pattern and move all forward data back toward the string beginning by two chars, tail filling with 0 ?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily create this with strstr:

```
char *strtok2(char *str, const char *pattern) {
    static char *save = NULL;
    if(str == NULL)
        str = save;
    if(str == NULL)
        return NULL;
    if((save=strstr(str, pattern))) {
        save[0]=0;
        save += strlen(pattern);
    }
    return str;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for off-topic.

strtok is not thread-safe. And you can't use strtok for each other values in same part. So you should no use. strtok is not difficult to write in your-self.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int
main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  char* p = "$%";
  size_t pl = strlen(p);
  char* s = "hello$%C$%language$%world";
  char* pp = s;
  while (pp && *pp) {
    char* pn = strstr(pp, p);
    if (!pn) pn = pp + strlen(pp);
    size_t l = pn - pp;
    char* ss = malloc(l + 1);
    *(ss + l) = 0;
    memcpy(ss, pp, l);

    // do something with ss
    puts(ss);

    free(ss);
    pp = pn + pl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```